# How to adopt multiple different loss functions in each steps of LSTM in Keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I have a set of sentences and their scores, I would like to train a marking system that could predict the score for a given sentence, such one example is like this:

```
(X =Tomorrow is a good day, Y = 0.9)
```

I would like to use LSTM to build such a marking system, and also consider the sequential relationship between each word in the sentence, so the training example shown above is transformed as following:

```
(x1=Tomorrow, y1=is) (x2=is, y2=a) (x3=a, y3=good) (x4=day, y4=0.9)
```

When training this LSTM, I would like the first three time steps using a softmax classifier, and the final step using a MSE. It is obvious that the loss function used in this LSTM is composed of two different loss functions. In this case, it seems the Keras does not provide the way to address my problem directly. In addition, I am not sure whether my method to build the marking system is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras support multiple loss functions as well:

```
   model = Model(inputs=inputs,
                 outputs=[lang_model, sent_model])

    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', 
                  loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'mse'],
                  metrics=['accuracy'], loss_weights=[1., 1.])
```

Based on your explanation, I think you need a model that first, predict a token based on previous tokens, in NLP domain it usually called [Language model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model), and then compute a score which I assume it is a sentiment (it is applicable to other domain).

To do so, you can train your language model with LSTM and pick the last output of LSTM for your ranking task. To this end, you need to define two loss function: `categorical_crossentropy` for the language model and `MSE` for the ranking task.

This tutorial would be helpful: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks very much for your reply. Does the "token" in your response mean the features of the sentence? i.e., the input for the softmax at the last time step?

Comment: @KevinSun I mean the things that you pass to your LSTM. It is usually word-vectors (Glove or w2v).

Comment: Thanks very much again. As I understood from the tutorial you referred, the multiple loss is built on different output layers that are without any connections. For example, if we want two losses, and these two losses are built on two layers named layer1 and layer2. From the tutorial, layer1 and layer3 have no connections to each other. In my problem, my losses are built on the outputs of layer3 and layer4, while the input of layer4 is the output of layer3. In this regard, could I use thses multiple losses?

Comment: Your welcome. You could but I am unsure about the convergence of the model.

Comment: Is your first reply to my question with the same meaning that I asked you in the previous post?

Comment: can you explain more? I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have no question any more. Thank you again.